# how to get rid of the error "‘class Agent’ has no member named x"

Tags: makefile, ns2

This is part of the code from a file in which I'm getting an error:

```
void MpegGenerator_v2::timeout()
{
    if (! running_)
            { printf("hola"); return; }

    if (mp_rec_.data != NULL) {
    if (mp_rec_.data->data() == NULL)
        agent_->sendmsg(size_);
    else {  

        paq_sending++;
        if((packettype==4)||(packettype==5)){
            if(mp_rec_.trec_size==-1) {  printf("4,5\n"); abort();}
            //printf("4 5 mp_rec_.trec_numframe=%d\n",mp_rec_.trec_numframe);
            agent_->sendmsg_priority(mp_rec_.trec_size, mp_rec_.data, mp_rec_.priority, packettype,mp_rec_.trec_numframe);

        }
        else {
            if(size_sli_paq[paq_sending-1]==-1) {  printf("else\n"); abort();}
            //printf("mp_rec_.trec_numframe=%d\n",mp_rec_.trec_numframe);
            agent_->sendmsg_priority(size_sli_paq[paq_sending-1], mp_rec_.data, mp_rec_.priority, packettype,mp_rec_.trec_numframe);
            size_sli_paq[paq_sending-1]=-1;
        }
    }

 } else {
    agent_->sendmsg(size_);

}
```

I'm getting the following error: `error: ‘class Agent’ has no member named ‘sendmsg_priority’`

Comment: Is it your code? I mean, if it is - you already know the answer; and if it isn't, why exactly do you need this? Anyway, question in current form is impossible to answer because it is too vague and doesn't contain relevant information. What the hell is this `Agent`? Why do you expect to call `sendmsg_priority` in it?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no method with that name, it's not there in `Class Agent`.

http://better-ns2-anim.sourceforge.net/javadoc/edu/colorado/cs/ns2/agents/Agent.html

Comment: I highly doubt you two talking about the same class :-)